# Disabling notifications for a host in Check_MK

Tags: monitoring, nagios, check-mk

I'm losing my mind trying to disable notifications for a specific host in Check_MK. For example, I want the host to be monitored - show up on the network topology and be able to see the problems on the host via the Check_MK views, but I don't want the server to send me an e-mail every time the host is disconnected and such things.

Am i missing something simple or is there a roundabout way of doing this?

Answer (score 5):

Do these:

1. Search for the host name on the main check_mk UI
2. Click on the hammer icon on the top (located under the page title "Services of Host ").
3. The UI that comes up is self-explanatory. You can either schedule a down time for the hosts (checks will be disabled) or you can simply disable notifications for selected or all of your services on that host.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to go to your Email Notifications: WATO -> Notification
and search for the Exclude the following Hosts. Just put the Hostname in there!
[image: exclude]